# Loop through rows then columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a range of data in excel which is uniform, Column A has a description, Column B has a unique ID and column C is blank. Then the next 3 columns have the same set of data. I am trying to get my vba loop to go down the two sets of data and compare the unique ID's, if there are differences it copies it to the range of data to a new sheet.

The issue is it is not just 6 columns of data its about a couple of hundred, so once the final row has been reached after checking the first range of data, the loop needs to move over 6 columns to begin the process again.

I am having some difficulty getting the loop to move across 6 columns once the finalrow has been reached

```
Sub finddata()

Dim s As Worksheet
Dim uniqueId As String
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim finalcolumn As Long
Dim offset As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

uniqueId = Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Data").Range("G100000").End(xlUp).Row
finalcolumn = Sheets("Data").Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
offset = 3

Set s = Sheets("Data")
Set rngSearch = s.Range(s.Cells(2, 5), s.Cells(finalrow, 5))

Sheets("DataValidation").Range("A1:C100000").ClearContents

If i = finalrow GoTo 'guessing this is how to being to loop to move over columns
    For i = 2 To finalrow
        uniqueId = s.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=uniqueId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If rngFound Is Nothing Then
            s.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
            Sheets("DataValidation").Range("A1048575").End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
    Next i

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: `If i = finalrow GoTo` you are missing where it needs to go. Also, can you explain a little more what are you intending? you clear columns A to C from datavalidation and then look for something on data, if not found you paste it to datavalidation?

Comment: Hey Damian, I put that there as I thought that would be the first step. So once i = final row (its looped through all the rows, then it would GoTo then next columns).

The script goes through and finds any non matching unique ID's in a range so it looks in three columns and compares against the next 3 columns and copy's any pastes any wrong data into a new sheet. It just clears the sheet to begin with

Comment: Usually you use nested loops to do that... It's fairly easy, but is hard for me to understand your goal... If you could edit your question and explain a little more what are you trying to do we could help.

Comment: Okay @Damian , I gave it a go to clear up the question. Hopefully it helps a bit. - thanks

Comment: So, once that you check the first to sets (columns A,B,C vs columns D,E,F), how should be the next interation?  A,B,C vs G,H,I?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego the intention is to go A,B,C vs D,E,F then move onto G,H,I vs J,K,L and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try that one

```
For j = 1 to finalcolumn step 6
    Set rngSearch = s.Range(s.Cells(2, j - 1 + 5), s.Cells(finalrow, j - 1 + 5))
    For i = 2 To finalrow
        uniqueId = s.Cells(i, 2 + j - 1).Value
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=uniqueId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                s.Range(Cells(i, 1 + j - 1), Cells(i, 6 + j - 1)).Copy
                Sheets("DataValidation").Range("A1048575").End(xlUp). _
                               offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I gave it a shot and works well for the first block of columns and moves to the next however it then keeps thinking that rngFound is Nothing after looping through the first 6 columns? Going to have to review the rngSearch variable to carry across with the loop

Comment: set rngsearch with in the second loop

Comment: Done. I didn't check it before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of how you can iterate on uniform ranges of 3 columns, and moving right by offset of 6. You said your ranges are uniform so I hard-coded the initial value of rngSet.

In the For Each I'm printing the address of the cells but you can do your checks there. The While loop will end when it reaches an empty cell.

```
Dim rngSet As Range, rngRow As Range

Set rngSet = Range("A1:B6")

While Not IsEmpty(rngSet.Cells(1, 1).Value)

    For Each rngRow In rngSet.Rows
        Debug.Print rngRow.Cells(1, 1).Address
    Next rngRow

    Set rngSet = rngSet.Offset(0, 6)
Wend
```